# same script on servers get error

Tags: bash, shell-script, case

I have this script on about 20 servers.

```
 CASE=$1

 case $CASE in
"multipath")
    status=$(service multipathd status | awk '{gsub(/[.]/,"");print $NF}')
        if [ $status = 'running' ]; then
        echo 0
        else
        echo 1
        fi
  ;;
"hbaport")
        output=0
    port_array=($(cat /sys/class/fc_host/*/port_state))
        for port in ${port_array[@]}
    do
            if [ $port != 'Online' ]; then
        output=1
            fi
        done
            echo $output
  ;;
"netface")
  inter=0
      ifconfig=$(ifconfig)
      interface_array=($(ls -l /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* | awk -F '-' '{print $NF}' | grep -iv 'lo'))
      for interface in ${interface_array[@]}
  do
  if [[ $ifconfig == *"$interface"* ]]; then
  operstate=$(cat /sys/class/net/$interface/operstate)
           if [ $operstate != 'up' ]; then
               inter=1
               fi
  fi
      done
      echo $inter
  ;;
 esac
```

when i run this command:
`/opt/zabbix_agent/share/scripts/OSscript "netface"`
it returns:
`0`
i just added this script to a new server and when i run above command i get this:

```
: command not foundhare/scripts/OSscript: line 2:
'opt/zabbix_agent/share/scripts/OSscript: line 3: syntax error near 
 unexpected token `in
'opt/zabbix_agent/share/scripts/OSscript: line 3: case $CASE in
```

why i get this error? OS is CentOS 6.9

Comment: Did you miss something during copy/paste? Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to analyse your script.

Comment: Looks like line endings are mucked up. Make sure there are no CR characters at the end of each line,

Comment: That case $CASE should be case "$CASE"

Comment: i checked with shellcheck. no serious error. CR? . "$CASE" didnt work.

Comment: CR is control-M (carriage return). The first line of the error output ": command not foundhare/scripts/OSscript: line 2:" looks like it is partially overwritten. use `cat -v` for example to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well according to icarus comment I used `cat -v` and saw that `^M` are considered as a part of command. I used these solutions at this post to remove them:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix
they did work on a test script not on OSscript. finally i found out that my files are corrupted. I removed OSscript and create it again and added my script. it worked.

Comment: If you say @icarus rather than icarus I will be notified of the answer.